# How to compare dates in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date

i want to compare two dates. i used this code

```
function addRow(dateval,bidchekval) {                       
    var val1 = document.getElementById(dateval);            

   var valcheck=document.getElementById(bidchekval).value;
   var val123=document.getElementById(dateval).value;

   if(val123 > valcheck ){
       alert("success");
   }
}
```

This is the code that i used but when change month then it will break.those two dates get using date picker.
date format example:06-12-2013 15:12:15

Comment: You're merely comparing 2 strings. And there's not enough information, in which format are those dates?

Comment: In what format are your dates?

Comment: date format example:06-12-2013 15:12:15

Answer (score 4):

```
if((new Date(val123).getTime()) > (new Date(valcheck).getTime()) ){
       alert("success");
   }
```

Comment: `.getTime()` is technically faster than `>` `<` comparisons operators that call the `ToPrimitive` algorithm on the Date objects. With `.getTime()`, `==`/`===` comparisons will also work, which do not work when comparing 2 Date objects.

Comment: Thanks for the info, Fabricio! I did it because i always work with milliseconds when dealing with date/time.

Comment: Though it is a bit in this case, I believe `.getTime()` is more clear as it shows what actually happens - the comparison happens between the 2 timestamps from those Date objects. (this conversion would be implicit otherwise)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot compare strings, but you can compare **[Date](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)** objects.

```
var valcheck=document.getElementById(bidchekval).value;
var val123=document.getElementById(dateval).value;

var check = new Date(valcheck) ;
var check123 = new Date(val123) ;

if (check > check123){
  alwer("Success") ;
}
```